# Specifying column ranges in CQL(1.1) using FIRST N

Tags: cassandra, cql

In [CQL docs 1.0](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/SELECT#examples) you could specify range of columns using the "FIRST N" attribute with a SELECT statement

In [CQL docs 1.1](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/SELECT#examples) it seems to be omitted, is this feature being removed from CQL, or is it still supported....perhaps in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's been removed. Here's the official [CQL3 doc](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectStmt):

> The `<select-clause>` determines which columns needs to be queried and
>   returned in the result-set. It consists of either the comma-separated
>   list of column names to query, or the wildcard character (*) to select
>   all the columns defined for the table.

Comment: do you have any idea how else to select a range of columns without knowing the column names

Answer (score 3):

So that there isn't any misunderstanding, the `WRITETIME` attribute isn't a replacement for `FIRST`, or even close to the same thing. The difference is that in CQL 3, wide cassandra rows are now modeled as narrow-looking CQL rows with multi-component primary keys.

For more information and introduction to the modeling changes (which really will make your life lots easier), see http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1 .

That said, you can still use CQL 2 and its `FIRST` clause and the `..` range operator, etc. to your heart's content. It's just deprecated.

Comment: thanks, do you have any idea how else to select a range of columns without knowing the column names, i'm abit worried about using the range or First(n) selectors if it will be deprecated/removed in future releases

Comment: You can still quite easily (or even more easily) do the same thing in CQL 3- it's just a different modeling approach, so the `FIRST` syntax doesn't apply. Do read that blog entry; it should explain how to change your model.